# What is the /etc/hosts behavior with alias or append?

Tags: linux, networking, host, hosts

I want to discover the behaviour of the system when I define in the /etc/hosts two separe entry with the same ip:

```
192.168.100.1     host1
192.168.100.1     host2
```

instead of:

```
192.168.100.1    host1     host2
```

The behaviour when I try to access the host1 changes?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As man said you should not:

This manual page describes the format of the /etc/hosts file. This file is a simple text file that associates IP addresses with hostnames, one line per IP address. For each host a single line should be present with the following information:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/102660/hosts-file-is-it-incorrect-to-have-the-same-ip-address-on-multiple-lines

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't know that the hosts file can be use from IP -> hostname.